# How to use MDC Slf4j for Concurrent Access

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, slf4j

We use SLF4J (with log4j) as our logging framework. We are trying to use MDC feature for concurrent access but it not working as expected for concurrent user.

I am putting appNo from the incoming request for logging. And, I am calling the host system and getting same appNo from MDC and logging for sending back response. After that, I remove the value from MDC. But, when we are accessing concurrently, the value is not logging in response logs in few cases. It seems, one thread is removing the value from MDC, other thread is accessing in the period. The appNo can be different in each request.

```
incoming(String appNo) {
    log.info(appNo);
    MDC.put("test", appNo);
}
```

**Sending Response back**

```
   String appNo = MDC.get("test");
   log.info(appNo);
   MDC.remove("test");
```

Is MDC thread safe for concurrent access? How to use the MDC for concurrent access?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of slf4j and log4j are you using.

Comment: Using slf4j 1.7.25 and 1.5.12.RELEASE spring boot log4j